# Error while fetching the listener data from the database in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, ellipse

I have been trying from last three days and i was not able to solve this problem;ed the tables and query.

I have been using perstlite for storing the data; I have created tables and queries for the required class;

Now I have been listening to contacts in the mobile and I am able to get the data in that class only but I am not able to get the information in the main class or any where in the project though i have called the class. Can anybody help me with this issue?

This is my program

```
package com.Wblower.listeners;



import java.util.Hashtable;

import javax.microedition.pim.Contact;
import javax.microedition.pim.PIMItem;
import javax.microedition.pim.PIMList;
import com.Wblower.db.ContactlistdatabaseQueries;
import com.Wblower.db.Contactlistdatabasetable;
import com.Wblower.db.DataBaseConnectivity;
import com.Wblower.util.DateTimeUtil;



import net.rim.blackberry.api.pdap.BlackBerryContact;
import net.rim.blackberry.api.pdap.BlackBerryContactList;
import net.rim.blackberry.api.pdap.PIMListListener;

public class ContactListener implements PIMListListener {

    BlackBerryContactList contactList;
    DataBaseConnectivity dbconnectVity = new DataBaseConnectivity();

    public void itemAdded(PIMItem arg0) {

        System.out.println("Item Added ==");
        String firstname = "none";
        String lastname = "none";
        String mobile = "none";
        String mobile1 = "none";
        String mobile2 = "none";
        String email = "none";
        String email1 = "none";
        String web = "none";
        String company = "none";
        String address = "none";
        String address1 = "none";
        String name[] = { "" };
        String timeStamp = "none";

        PIMList contacts = arg0.getPIMList();
        Contact contact = (Contact) arg0;

        if (contacts.isSupportedField(Contact.NAME)) {

            try {
                if (contact.countValues(Contact.NAME) > 0)
                    name = contact.getStringArray(Contact.NAME, 0);
                if (name[Contact.NAME_GIVEN] != null)
                    firstname = name[Contact.NAME_GIVEN];
                System.out.println("FirstName= " + firstname);
                if (name[Contact.NAME_FAMILY] != null)
                    lastname = name[Contact.NAME_FAMILY];
                System.out.println("LastName= " + lastname);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception::" + e.getMessage());
            }

        }
        if (contacts.isSupportedField(Contact.EMAIL)) {
            try {
                if (contact.countValues(Contact.EMAIL) > 0)
                    email = contact.getString(Contact.EMAIL, 0);
                System.out.println("Email " + email);

                if (contact.countValues(Contact.EMAIL) > 1)
                    email1 = contact.getString(Contact.EMAIL, 1);
                System.out.println("Email " + email1);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception::" + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        if (contacts.isSupportedField(Contact.ORG)) {

            try {
                if (contact.countValues(Contact.ORG) > 0)
                    company = contact.getString(Contact.ORG, 0);
                System.out.println("Company " + company);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception::" + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        if (contacts.isSupportedField(Contact.URL)) {
            try {
                if (contact.countValues(Contact.URL) > 0)
                    web = contact.getString(Contact.URL, 0);
                System.out.println("web " + web);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception::" + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        if (contacts.isSupportedField(Contact.TEL)) {
            try {
                if (contact.countValues(Contact.TEL) > 0)
                    mobile = contact.getString(Contact.TEL, 0);
                System.out.println("Phone " + mobile);

                if (contact.countValues(Contact.TEL) > 1)
                    mobile1 = contact.getString(Contact.TEL, 1);
                System.out.println("Phone " + mobile1);

                if (contact.countValues(Contact.TEL) > 2)
                    mobile2 = contact.getString(Contact.TEL, 2);
                System.out.println("Phone " + mobile2);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception::" + e.getMessage());
            }
            if (contacts.isSupportedField(Contact.ADDR)) {

                try {
                    address = "";
                    String[] addressarr = contact.getStringArray(
                            BlackBerryContact.ADDR, 0);

                    for (int i = 0; i < addressarr.length; i++) {

                        if (addressarr[i] != null) {
                            address = address + " " + addressarr[i];

                        }

                    }
                    System.out.println("Address==" + address);

                    address1 = "";
                    String[] addressar = contact.getStringArray(
                            BlackBerryContact.ADDR, 1);

                    for (int i = 0; i < addressar.length; i++) {
                        if (addressar[i] != null) {
                            address1 = address1 + " " + addressar[i];

                        }

                    }
                    System.out.println("Address==" + address1);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Exception::" + e.getMessage());
                }

                timeStamp = DateTimeUtil.timestamp();

                try {

                    System.out.println("Entering into the db");
                    dbconnectVity.setDataBase();
                    Contactlistdatabasetable Contactlist;
                    Contactlist = new Contactlistdatabasetable(
                            "Contacts", "Add", firstname, lastname, mobile,
                            mobile1, mobile2, email, email1, web, company,
                            address, address1, timeStamp);
                    ContactlistdatabaseQueries.insertSingleContactlist(Contactlist);
                    ContactlistdatabaseQueries.selectWholeContactlist();         
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Exception::" + e.getMessage());
                }

                return;

            }

        }

    }

    public void itemRemoved(PIMItem arg0) {
        System.out.println("Item Removed ==");
        String firstname = "none";
        String lastname = "none";
        String mobile = "none";
        String mobile1 = "none";
        String mobile2 = "none";
        String email = "none";
        String email1 = "none";
        String web = "none";
        String company = "none";
        String address = "none";
        String address1 = "none";
        String name[] = { "" };
        String timeStamp = "none";

        PIMList contacts = arg0.getPIMList();
        Contact contact = (Contact) arg0;

        if (contacts.isSupportedField(Contact.NAME)) {

            try {
                if (contact.countValues(Contact.NAME) > 0)
                    name = contact.getStringArray(Contact.NAME, 0);
                if (name[Contact.NAME_GIVEN] != null)
                    firstname = name[Contact.NAME_GIVEN];
                System.out.println("FirstName= " + firstname);
                if (name[Contact.NAME_FAMILY] != null)
                    lastname = name[Contact.NAME_FAMILY];
                System.out.println("LastName= " + lastname);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception::" + e.getMessage());
            }

        }
        if (contacts.isSupportedField(Contact.EMAIL)) {
            try {
                if (contact.countValues(Contact.EMAIL) > 0)
                    email = contact.getString(Contact.EMAIL, 0);
                System.out.println("Email " + email);

                if (contact.countValues(Contact.EMAIL) > 1)
                    email1 = contact.getString(Contact.EMAIL, 1);
                System.out.println("Email " + email1);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception::" + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        if (contacts.isSupportedField(Contact.ORG)) {

            try {
                if (contact.countValues(Contact.ORG) > 0)
                    company = contact.getString(Contact.ORG, 0);
                System.out.println("Company " + company);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception::" + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        if (contacts.isSupportedField(Contact.URL)) {
            try {
                if (contact.countValues(Contact.URL) > 0)
                    web = contact.getString(Contact.URL, 0);
                System.out.println("web " + web);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception::" + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        if (contacts.isSupportedField(Contact.TEL)) {
            try {
                if (contact.countValues(Contact.TEL) > 0)
                    mobile = contact.getString(Contact.TEL, 0);
                System.out.println("Phone " + mobile);

                if (contact.countValues(Contact.TEL) > 1)
                    mobile1 = contact.getString(Contact.TEL, 1);
                System.out.println("Phone " + mobile1);

                if (contact.countValues(Contact.TEL) > 2)
                    mobile2 = contact.getString(Contact.TEL, 2);
                System.out.println("Phone " + mobile2);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception::" + e.getMessage());
            }
            if (contacts.isSupportedField(Contact.ADDR)) {

                try {
                    address = "";
                    String[] addressarr = contact.getStringArray(
                            BlackBerryContact.ADDR, 0);

                    for (int i = 0; i < addressarr.length; i++) {

                        if (addressarr[i] != null) {
                            address = address + " " + addressarr[i];

                        }

                    }
                    System.out.println("Address==" + address);

                    address1 = "";
                    String[] addressar = contact.getStringArray(
                            BlackBerryContact.ADDR, 1);

                    for (int i = 0; i < addressar.length; i++) {

                        if (addressar[i] != null) {
                            address1 = address1 + " " + addressar[i];

                        }

                    }
                    System.out.println("Address==" + address1);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Exception::" + e.getMessage());
                }

                timeStamp = DateTimeUtil.timestamp();

                try {
                    System.out.println("Entering into the db");
                    dbconnectVity.setDataBase();
                    Contactlistdatabasetable Contactlist;
                    Contactlist = new Contactlistdatabasetable(
                            "Contacts", "Delete", firstname, lastname, mobile,
                            mobile1, mobile2, email, email1, web, company,
                            address, address1, timeStamp);
                    ContactlistdatabaseQueries.insertSingleContactlist(Contactlist);
                    ContactlistdatabaseQueries.selectWholeContactlist();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Exception::" + e.getMessage());
                }

                return;
            }
        }

    }

    public void itemUpdated(PIMItem arg0, PIMItem arg1) {
        System.out.println("Item Updated ==");
        String firstname = "none";
        String lastname = "none";
        String mobile = "none";
        String mobile1 = "none";
        String mobile2 = "none";
        String email = "none";
        String email1 = "none";
        String web = "none";
        String company = "none";
        String address = "none";
        String address1 = "none";
        String name[] = { "" };
        String timeStamp = "none";

        PIMList contacts = arg1.getPIMList();
        Contact contact = (Contact) arg1;

        if (contacts.isSupportedField(Contact.NAME)) {

            try {
                if (contact.countValues(Contact.NAME) > 0)
                    name = contact.getStringArray(Contact.NAME, 0);
                if (name[Contact.NAME_GIVEN] != null)
                    firstname = name[Contact.NAME_GIVEN];
                System.out.println("FirstName= " + firstname);
                if (name[Contact.NAME_FAMILY] != null)
                    lastname = name[Contact.NAME_FAMILY];
                System.out.println("LastName= " + lastname);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception::" + e.getMessage());
            }

        }
        if (contacts.isSupportedField(Contact.EMAIL)) {
            try {
                if (contact.countValues(Contact.EMAIL) > 0)
                    email = contact.getString(Contact.EMAIL, 0);
                System.out.println("Email " + email);

                if (contact.countValues(Contact.EMAIL) > 1)
                    email1 = contact.getString(Contact.EMAIL, 1);
                System.out.println("Email " + email1);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception::" + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        if (contacts.isSupportedField(Contact.ORG)) {

            try {
                if (contact.countValues(Contact.ORG) > 0)
                    company = contact.getString(Contact.ORG, 0);
                System.out.println("Company " + company);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception::" + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        if (contacts.isSupportedField(Contact.URL)) {
            try {
                if (contact.countValues(Contact.URL) > 0)
                    web = contact.getString(Contact.URL, 0);
                System.out.println("web " + web);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception::" + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        if (contacts.isSupportedField(Contact.TEL)) {
            try {
                if (contact.countValues(Contact.TEL) > 0)
                    mobile = contact.getString(Contact.TEL, 0);
                System.out.println("Phone " + mobile);

                if (contact.countValues(Contact.TEL) > 1)
                    mobile1 = contact.getString(Contact.TEL, 1);
                System.out.println("Phone " + mobile1);

                if (contact.countValues(Contact.TEL) > 2)
                    mobile2 = contact.getString(Contact.TEL, 2);
                System.out.println("Phone " + mobile2);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception::" + e.getMessage());
            }
            if (contacts.isSupportedField(Contact.ADDR)) {

                try {
                    address = "";
                    String[] addressarr = contact.getStringArray(
                            BlackBerryContact.ADDR, 0);

                    for (int i = 0; i < addressarr.length; i++) {

                        if (addressarr[i] != null) {
                            address = address + " " + addressarr[i];

                        }

                    }
                    System.out.println("Address==" + address);
                    address1 = "";
                    String[] addressar = contact.getStringArray(
                            BlackBerryContact.ADDR, 1);

                    for (int i = 0; i < addressar.length; i++) {
                        if (addressar[i] != null) {
                            address1 = address1 + " " + addressar[i];

                        }

                    }
                    System.out.println("Address==" + address1);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Exception::" + e.getMessage());
                }

                timeStamp = DateTimeUtil.timestamp();

                try {
                    System.out.println("Entering into the db");
                    dbconnectVity.setDataBase();
                    Contactlistdatabasetable Contactlist;
                    Contactlist = new Contactlistdatabasetable(
                            "Contacts", "Update", firstname, lastname, mobile,
                            mobile1, mobile2, email, email1, web, company,
                            address, address1, timeStamp);
                    ContactlistdatabaseQueries.insertSingleContactlist(Contactlist);
                    ContactlistdatabaseQueries.selectWholeContactlist();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Exception::" + e.getMessage());
                }

                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope u have understood my problem

When I have selected "ContactlistdatabaseQueries.selectWholeContactlist();"  this method in any main class i am not able to fetch the data in the database, the response when i am getting is 0. but i need to get the value of the stored data i.e number of rows inserted.

Answer (score 0):

i have got my problem sloved it is nothing but just changing the database,
 ihave used perstlite in the issue but persistent will be the better one for the above problem